# Getting 'max call stack size exceeded' when incrementing a node in Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to increment my 'week' value in firebase by 1.

One solution i've been trying was this:

```
var ref = db.ref();
    ref.on('value', function (data) {
        var week = data.val().week + 1;
        ref.update({
            week
        });
    });
```

but it throws a "max call stack size exceeded" error (Even though firebase still updates appropriately)

I also tried

```
var ref = db.ref('week');
    ref.on('value', function (data) {
        var week = data.val();
        ref.set(week+1);
    });
```

this works as well, but it throws the same error

Can someone provide a solution that doesn't throw an error? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you're using `on()` to read the data.  When you use on(), you're setting up a listener that gets invoked any time the data at the location changes.  So what you have written does this:

1. Listen to the location 'week'
2. When the value is known, **or when it has changed**, get it from the snapshot
3. Increment the value by 1, and write it back to 'week'
4. Since the value of 'week' has changed, goto step 2 so the listener can process the change.

This effectively an infinite loop.

If you just want to increment a single time, use [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#once) instead of on() to [read data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once).